# How to tie VSS.getWebContext().user.id to an AAD user?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on an extension that will add a form in a Work Item that pulls data from my WebApi. I have it working with the token from GetAppToken(), and the token that comes into my Api has the id that corresponds to VSS.getWebContext().user.id (which is the only user identifier that is sent). In my API, however, I need to check some properties in AAD graph. It does not appear as though the Id for the user in VSS has any relation to anything I can find in AAD (even though the user object has Type:AAD).

What is the user object in this context and how do I tie that to the user that I would look up in Graph?

thanks,
~john